# Storing and retrieving image in sql server using Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I want to store image in **SQL server using Codeigniter**; actually I can select image and convert it but when I do that and store it in database then retrieve it the image cannot display.

What I observed in database the previous name for images that stored using C# begins with 0xFFD8F but using codeigniter the name begins with 0x3 or anything else.

here the **controller**

```
public function addImage() {
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload()) {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('Profile/addImage', $error);
    } else {
        $data = $this->upload->data(); 
        $dataString = file_get_contents($data['full_path']);
        $orig_name = $data['orig_name'];
        $uploadImage = $this->Personalinfo_model->uploadImage(array('orig_name' => $orig_name, 'dataString' => $dataString ));
        delete_files($data['full_path']) ;
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
function uploadImage($options = array()) {
    $orig_name = $options['orig_name']; 
    $dataString = $options['dataString']; 
    // $hex_image = bin2hex($dataString);
    $data = unpack("H*hex", $dataString);
    $object = array(
        'EmployeeID' => '3',
        'filename' => $orig_name,
        'EmployeePic' => "0x".$data['hex']
    );
    $this->db->where('EmployeeID','3');
    $this->db->update('EmployeePic', $object);
}
```

After unpack image something wrong gonna happened, but i can not detect the problem.

Comment: you should just save the image path not the image itself. otherwise you will end up with huge amount of storage in db server and bad performance.

Comment: I get full path using **file_get_contents($data['full_path']);**

Comment: file get path would return file information, not the file itself. what would you do is either to store the image name or image path with name then just echo it.

Comment: but $data['full_path'] return file it self without any information, if it was not, so what shall I use.

Comment: what is the output of `$data['full_path']`?

Comment: C:/xampp/htdocs/HC/uploads/smiley-face3.jpg

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42393/discussion-between-mamdouh-alramadan-and-doksh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in the Chat side, you have the function as follows:

```
function uploadImage($options = array()) { 
    $orig_name = $options['orig_name']; 
    $dataString = $options['dataString']; 
    $hex_image = bin2hex($dataString); 

    $object = array( 
        'EmployeeID' => '3', 
        'filename' => $orig_name, 
        'EmployeePic' => "0x".$hex_image 
    ); 
    $this->db->where('EmployeeID','3'); 

    $this->db->update('[HumanResource].[dbo].[EmployeePic]', $object); 
}
```

And you are concatenating `0x` string to your binary. by removing it you should have your function working properly.